# How can I add an audio menu in the Finder?

Tags: finder, audio

What is the easiest way to add menu item to finder that switched audio from internal to external(headphone). I have to switch back and forth often and going into control panel every time is a pain in Snow leopard. Is there a way to do this with Applescript?

Answer (score 4):

You can <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click the volume menu in the menu bar to quickly select which audio output device to use.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways that I know of.

Hold option and click on the volume icon in the finder to get a list of input/output options.

The other option is to download an app called [SoundSource.](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/)

[image: SoundSource]